# Understanding PAC (probably approximately correct) bounds on the realizable case (and finite hypothesis class)

Tags: probability-theory, machine-learning

I was trying to understand PAC bounds on the realizable case (i.e. when there is some perfect $h^* \in \mathcal{H}$ and its generalization error is zero).

---

Notation:

Training data:
$$S_n$$
Training error on training data $S_n$
$$\mathcal{E_{n}(h)}$$
Generalization error
$$\mathcal{E(h)}$$
Hypothesis class
$$\mathcal{H}$$
Size of hypothesis class:
$$|\mathcal{H}| = K$$
Probability over the choice of training set that the PAC bound fails:
$$\delta$$

---

I would like to derive how $\epsilon$ relates to other PAC variables, n, $K$ and $\delta$.

Attempted derivation:

Let $h_{bad}$ be any classifier that generalizes poorly $\mathcal{E(h)} > \epsilon$ . What is the probability that we would choose it after seeing the training set? If we choose it then given the current $S_n$ then we would choose it, if it has zero training error. Then, what is the probability that this bad classifier makes no training error?

$$P[h_{bad} \text{makes no error on } S_n] = (1 - \mathcal{E(h)})^n < (1-\epsilon)^n$$

this number is an upper bound on the "fraction/precentage of classifiers" that are bad and are chosen with the current training data.

From this I was trying to relate that upper bound to $\delta$ and was trying to figure out if the following statement was true:

$$(1 - \mathcal{E(h)})^n = \delta$$

If its true then one can conclude that:

$$\delta < (1-\epsilon)^n$$

Which is the bound that makes sense to me, but it seems that I am missing one important variable $|\mathcal{H}| = k$. For some reason the correct bound is suppose to be $\delta \leq |\mathcal{H}|(1-\epsilon)^n|$ but I can't figure out why. I think my problem is that I can't seem to understand what the difference of $\delta$ and $1 - \mathcal{E(h)})^n$ is, or the relation between them. I believe I got the correct relation but I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

$P[h_{bad} \text{makes no error on } S_n]$ is the probability that a *particular* bad classifier would work on the training data. To get a bound on the probability that *any* bad classifier would work on the training data, we need to multiply by the number of potentially bad classifiers, $K$.